# Merge two SELECT statements which have one or more additional columns

Tags: sql, select, merge

I have two select statements like below

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```

gives me

```
COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMNC
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

gives me

```
COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMND
```

COLUMNA, COLUMNB are identical(same number of rows and cell values) in those two SELECTs

How can I merge these two SELECTs so I can have four columns with one query and no extra rows

```
COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMNC, COLUMND
```

Updating my question based on comments. Let's say I have two tables like below

```
TABLE1                     TABLE2
COLUMNA COLUMNB COLUMNC    COLUMNA COLUMNB COLUMND
value1  value2  value3     value1  value2  value9
value4  null    value5     value4  null    value10
null    value6  value7     null    value6  value11
null    null    value8     null    null    value12
```

result should be

```
COLUMNA COLUMNB COLUMNC    COLUMND
value1  value2  value3     value9
value4  null    value5     value10
null    value6  value7     value11
null    null    value8     value12
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"?  Please edit your question with some sample data and desired results.

Comment: MERGE those two SELECT queries into one query

Comment: @yalkris It is not clear what exactly you mean by merge. The two record sets have different column names. Define that merge operation more rigorously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this.

```
SELECT COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMNC, NULL as COLUMND FROM TABLE1 

UNION 

SELECT COLUMNA, COLUMNB, NULL as COLUMNC, COLUMND FROM TABLE2
```

or maybe:

```
SELECT COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMNC FROM TABLE1 

UNION 

SELECT COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMND as COLUMNC FROM TABLE2
```

Comment: This query gave duplicate rows with columnC and columnD having null values

Answer (score 2):

This will give you 3 columns, the third being the different valued one:

```
SELECT 
 COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMNC AS [Column3]
FROM TABLE1 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
 COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMND AS [Column3]
FROM TABLE2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.COLUMNA, A.COLUMNB, A.COLUMNC, B.COLUMND 
FROM TABLE1 A
JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.COLUMNA = B.COLUMNA AND A.COLUMNB = B.COLUMNB
```

And if there is a row that are not identicall in columnA and columnB or not exists, and you want it on the result use:

```
SELECT A.COLUMNA, A.COLUMNB, A.COLUMNC, B.COLUMND 
FROM TABLE1 A
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.COLUMNA = B.COLUMNA AND A.COLUMNB = B.COLUMNB
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you indicate the rows and values for `ColumnA` and `ColumnB` are identical, you can `JOIN` the two tables together if the values are the same

```
SELECT a.ColumnA
      ,a.ColumnB
      ,a.ColumnC
      ,b.ColumnD
FROM Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b
  ON a.ColumnA = b.ColumnA
  AND a.ColumnB = b.ColumnB
```

If you have disparity between the two tables, i.e. some records in one but not the other, you can use `FULL JOIN` and change the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.ColumnA,b.ColumnA) AS ColumnA
      ,COALESCE(a.ColumnB,b.ColumnB) AS ColumnB
      ,a.ColumnC
      ,b.ColumnD
FROM Table1 a
FULL JOIN Table2 b
  ON a.ColumnA = b.ColumnA
  AND a.ColumnB = b.ColumnB
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I have few null s as cell values

Comment: @yalkris The bottom query would return `NULL` valued records, but would be on separate rows if present in both tables, it was unclear from the question what exactly you were going for.